# Extracting sequences from columns using R

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence

I have a `df` which looks like this

```
ID  X003-APP    X005-APP    X008-APP    X003-COP    X004-COP    X008-PIN    X009-PIN
363 NA          NA          1           0           NA          4          5
364 0           2           NA          1           5           1          5
678 0           NA          NA          5           NA          NA         NA
713 1           1           1           1           1           1          1
219 1           2           3           3           NA          4          5
234 NA          NA          NA          2           3           NA         NA
321 2           3           1           NA          NA          1          2
```

I am interested in minimum counts for non-null values across the column substrings `APP`, `COP` and `PIN`. My required output is:

```
ID     APP  COP PIN
363    1    1   1
364    1    1   1
678    1    1   0
713    1    1   1
219    1    1   1
234    0    1   0
321    1    0   1
```

For reference, I am sharing the dput():

```
structure(list(ID = c(363L, 364L, 678L, 713L, 219L, 234L, 321L), 
X003.APP = c(NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L), 
X005.APP = c(NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 3L), 
X008.APP = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L), 
X003.COP = c(0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA), 
X004.COP = c(NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA), 
X008.PIN = c(4L, 1L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 1L), 
X009.PIN = c(5L, 5L, NA, 1L, 5L, NA, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

##### Edit:

Later on, I would like to analyse 2 and 3 sequences across IDs. For example, I am ultimately, interested in minimum counts for non-null values across the column substrings `APP`, `COP` and `PIN`. My ultimate required output for a sequence of length 2 would be:

```
Spec_1  Spec_2  Counts
APP     COP     5
APP     PIN     5
COP     PIN     4
```

Or correspondingly, my required output for a sequence of length 3 would be:

```
Spec_1  Spec_2  Spec_3 Counts
APP     COP     PIN    4
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? It would be great to have a solution that could cater for longer sequences - even beyond 3. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Does previous required output is not needed?

Comment: Thanks Park. The previous requirement is indeed my final requirement. Let me update that in the question.

Comment: Your `dput` is defective because of the invalid column names. We cannot reproduce your data.

Comment: I changed the names to stop them from looking messy. But now I have updated them. I hope dput() works for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  reshape2::melt(id = "ID") %>%
  separate(variable, into = c("a", "Spec"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  group_by(ID, Spec) %>%
  summarize(value = as.numeric(any(!is.na(value)))) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Spec", values_from = "value") %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

     ID   APP   COP   PIN
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   219     1     1     1
2   234     0     1     0
3   321     1     0     1
4   363     1     1     1
5   364     1     1     1
6   678     1     1     0
7   713     1     1     1
```

Is your edited one and

```
df %>%
  reshape2::melt(id = "ID") %>%
  separate(variable, into = c("a", "Spec"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  group_by(ID, Spec) %>%
  summarize(value = any(!is.na(value))) %>%
  filter(value) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  summarise(Spec = combn(Spec, 2, simplify = F)) %>%
  unnest_wider(Spec, names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(Spec_1, Spec_2) %>%
  summarize(Counts = n())

  Spec_1 Spec_2 Counts
  <chr>  <chr>   <int>
1 APP    COP         5
2 APP    PIN         5
3 COP    PIN         4
```

is your previous one.

## 3 seq?

```
df %>%
  reshape2::melt(id = "ID") %>%
  separate(variable, into = c("a", "Spec"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  group_by(ID, Spec) %>%
  summarize(value = any(!is.na(value))) %>%
  filter(value) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() > 2) %>%
  summarise(Spec = combn(Spec, 3, simplify = F)) %>%
  unnest_wider(Spec, names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(Spec_1, Spec_2, Spec_3) %>%
  summarize(Counts = n())

  Spec_1 Spec_2 Spec_3 Counts
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <int>
1 APP    COP    PIN         4
```

Comment: Thank you, @Park. Can this solution correspondingly be expanded to a length 3 sequences?

Comment: @Sandy If your **length 3 sequences** means combinations of three, then it works, with slightly edit of them. I add the code for that. Please let me know if there are too many to write all `Spec_...` in `group_by` part.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is efficient in that I do not need to provide column names. I just needed to update the regex expression as per my original dataset.
The rest is working fine. Also, I like how this can be expanded beyond length 2 sequence into length 3 sequences and hopefully even beyond.
Can it similarly be expanded to length 4 sequences by changing the code lines ```summarise(Spec = combn(Spec, 4, simplify = F))``` and then ```group_by(Spec_1, Spec_2, Spec_3) %>%``` ?

Comment: And this '''filter(n() > 3)'''

Comment: @Sandy For length `n` sequences, you may use `combn(Spec, n, simplify = F))` and `group_by(across(-ID))`.

Comment: And `filter(n() > n - 1)`.

Comment: Many thanks, @Park , I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df |> rowwise() |> transmute( ID,
APP = case_when(all(is.na(c_across(contains("APP")))) ~ 0 , TRUE ~ 1) ,
COP = case_when(all(is.na(c_across(contains("COP")))) ~ 0 , TRUE ~ 1) , 
PIN = case_when(all(is.na(c_across(contains("PIN")))) ~ 0 , TRUE ~ 1)) -> df1
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     ID   APP   COP   PIN
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   363     1     1     1
2   364     1     1     1
3   678     1     1     0
4   713     1     1     1
5   219     1     1     1
6   234     0     1     0
7   321     1     0     1
```

- for your second required you can use

```
df1 |> transmute(AC = case_when(sum(c_across(c(APP,COP))) == 2 ~ 1 , TRUE ~ 0) ,
AP = case_when(sum(c_across(c(APP,PIN))) == 2 ~ 1 , TRUE ~ 0) ,
CP = case_when(sum(c_across(c(PIN,COP))) == 2 ~ 1 , TRUE ~ 0) ,
ACP = case_when(sum(c_across(c(APP,COP,PIN))) == 3 ~ 1 , TRUE ~ 0)) |> ungroup() |> 
summarise(APP_COP = sum(AC) , APP_PIN = sum(AP) , COP_PIN = sum(CP) ,  APP_COP_PIN = sum(ACP))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  APP_COP APP_PIN COP_PIN APP_COP_PIN
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1       5       5       4           4
```

Comment: Thank you, Mohamed, for the solution. Is it possible to change the first solution as the number of columns in my actual data-frame are variable. There are 100s of columns and they do not appear in order.

Comment: Try this now...

Comment: Can the column selection be done with a command like this? ```dataf %>%
  select(ends_with('APP'))```

Comment: Yes , of course ,

Comment: Could you please suggest how to make this change in your code? I tried but did not work for me.

Comment: Would you print `colnames(df)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246607/discussion-between-sandy-and-mohamed-desouky).

Comment: Yes, it is:
``` "ID"       "X003.APP" "X005.APP" "X008.APP" "X003.COP" "X004.COP" "X008.PIN"
"X009.PIN" ```

Comment: Just try it and it works.

Comment: Yes, it is working for the sample, thank you. Let me try it on the main data set.

Comment: I've tried on my actual data set. The first instruction is taking a long time. I am waiting for it to get completed. The reason might be that I have nearly 200 columns and around 4000 rows in my original dataset.

The code it still running. Either it is slow or that RStudio is now stuck :(